# Cant see my developed widget

Tags: android, android-widget, cyanogenmod

So i developed a widget for android. It all worked fine when i had
default samsung ROM for my sgs3 (android 4.1), 
But when i updated my android version to 4.2.2(CM10) i don't see my widget under
'Widgets' category in the android menu.
here is my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="ToDoListWidget"
              android:label="ToDoList"
              android:icon="@drawable/icon" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/items_widget" />
    </receiver>
```

and here is my appwidget-provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="320dp"
    android:resizeMode="vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="100000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Any ideas what should i cahnge?

**EDIT:**
Hey, please help me with this one, it happend again right now when i 
create a widget in another app.
Is the problem in my code? in my device? in my SDK?

Comment: I've had widgets disappear from the menu when installing/updating an app, and re-installing the app fixed it.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: already tried it. still not fixing it. thanks anyway, althought i install it from eclipse. did you install it from apk or from IDE?

Comment: i was also using eclipse

Comment: forgot to mention but i also noticed that the problem occured after i updated the SDK, can it be a couse?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe CyanogenMod does this *clever thing* of moving your app to the SD card automatically if possible

And **any app that is on the SD card cannot add a widget to the home screen** (as when the SD card is mounted to a PC the widget would disappear and this would be "strange").

So check your app isn't on the SD card. You might want `internalOnly` or `preferInternal` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Already tried the "internalOnly" option, although i dont have SD card on my device

Comment: YOu may not have an SD, but you have an internal storage taht acts like an SD i.e. is mountable